# Scale div with aspect ratio

Tags: css, scale

I have a div with text and image contents and an aspect ratio of 16:9. Now I want to make a preview for that in another div with a fix width. 
When I try to do that as shown here 
http://jsfiddle.net/2800do8j/

I have two problems:

1. Either the shown div (blue background) is too small when using CSS transform scale or font is not minimized.
2. I don't want that sroll bar on x-Axis, but I need it on y-Axis if I got several div-previews one below the other.

Can you give me some advise how to solve that problem?

This is the relevant CSS part:

```
.bla {
    width:1132px; 
    height:637px;
    position: block;
    -ms-transform: scale(0.33,0.33); 
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.33,0.33); 
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: scale(0.33,0.33);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

(by the way: why do you have to add code when using jsfiddle?)

Comment: You add code in case the JSfiddle is not available in future.

Comment: For your second problem you can use overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto; but note that this is css3 so it won't work on older browsers.